# Sum values using each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to return the sum of values ​​every time one of the select is changed. But the sum is always wrong:

```
$('select').change(function () {
 a = 0;
 $('select').each(function () {
    a += parseInt($('option:selected').val(), 10);
 });
 $('h1 span').html(a);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vAu3E/

Comment: `var sum = $("select option:selected").toArray().reduce(function(sum, val) { return sum+val; }, 0);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var a = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        a += parseInt(this[this.selectedIndex].value, 10);
    });
    $('h1 span').html(a);
});
```

#### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAu3E/8/)

Answer (score 4):

Use `this.value` (faster than re-getting a jQuery object when you already have it) and declare `a` so it's not global (I also invoked the handler immediately so your result shows immediately):

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var a = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
         a += parseInt(this[this.selectedIndex].value, 10); //originally this.value
    });
    $('h1 span').html(a);
}).change();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vAu3E/10/

See comments for potential issues with `this.value` in versions of IE

Comment: Why is `this.value` better? It'll fail in most IE browsers.

Comment: @cookiemonster -- No point in initializing another jQuery object when you're already iterating over the set - and it targets the current element - not a generic `option:selected`

Comment: Don't call .value on a select box, either use `$(this).val()` or use it's options to read the value: `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value` - selectbox.value is undefined on some browsers.

Comment: @scragar -- what browsers?

Comment: IE *(I think maybe even version 11)* doesn't give the `select` elements a `.value` property. It can be shimmed of course.

Comment: I'm paranoid, so now I need to go and verify, but I have a shim as part of my standard library so I'm pretty confident. I'll check back to confirm.

Comment: ...the `option` elements do have a `.value`, so if the original selector was used, it would work.

Comment: @cookiemonster I believe the issue was hotfixed in 8, and fixed for good in 9, but given jQuery 1.9 branch supports IE 7 I think it's a nice consideration.

Comment: @scragar: I think you may be right about the versions. I'm getting a correct value in IE10.

Comment: Sorry @tymeJV, I was too broad with the IE versions. scragar seems to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

Using **sum** plugin , you will have :

```
$('select').change(function () {
    $('h1 span').html($('option:selected').sum());
});
```

### FIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/vAu3E/18/

## NOTE

You use `val` method since your element is `option` tag. But ,  If It is a sum of DIV content elements for example , You must use `html` method instead of `val` :

So , the sum plugin still useful :

```
   $('div.operators').sum('html');
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    var a = 0;
    $("select").each(function(){
        a += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('h1 span').html(a);
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAu3E/16/)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the result is correct, because you have to substitute "option:selected" with this:

```
a += parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
```

If you put "option:selected" the selector is the first selector, instead with $(this) you get the value of each select...

Hope that this comment help you...
Bye

Answer (score 1):

There's an alternative to `parseInt`; prepending a `+` will convert a 'numeric` string into a number:

```
$('select').change(function () {
    var a = 0;
    $('select').each(function () {
        a += +this.value;
    });
    $('h1 span').html(a);
});
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/vAu3E/20/)